numbering indents
I want to do some variant of the exam on an A4 sheet. So, in another question I asked how to make numbering in a frame. But I found out one problem that when I use “\\” to move the text, the transferred text goes to the left outside the numbering frame as on this picture:

I need to keep the text within the numbering frame as in this picture:

I came up with one way but I think it's not very practical because I just approximated the indentation and it's not very accurate. Here is all the code including my method:
\documentclass{exam}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\framebox[1cm]{\thequestion}}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question Something \textit{interesting}\\ \-\hspace{0.441cm} Something more \textit{interesting}
\end{questions}

\end{document}


You need to change the \leftmargin and \labelwidth.
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{\framebox[1cm]{\thequestion}}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \settowidth{\leftmargin}{\framebox[1cm]{}}%
  \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\labelsep}%
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{\dimeval{\leftmargin+\labelsep}}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question \lipsum[30][1-4]

\question[10] \lipsum[30][1-4]
\end{questions}

\end{document}


